# How to Extract Payment response?

Tags: php

I'm integrating payment gateway of PayTM to my using android and PHP I got this type of response. How can I extract the code using PHP and store it to the Mysql database?

The Response Code is:-

```
[
    {
    STATUS=TXN_SUCCESS, 
    CHECKSUMHASH=hMgfJKzp6a2W91+wVQ71qd58nfvyEsLPgNrnvnYSRYpXDf9YB6+vdtYyejB2w1ZUt1MG8TiASW/jWBRnDO84MM3OlM/+1e5T2tmQ3JasAIw=, 
    BANKNAME=Bank, 
    ORDERID=789ERJSO5HAG, 
    TXNAMOUNT=73.00, 
    TXNDATE=2019-10-27 16:16:39.0, 
    MID=NGtbUJ50332856675382, 
    TXNID=20191027111212800110168691700967146, 
    RESPCODE=01, 
    PAYMENTMODE=DC, 
    BANKTXNID=778001546502320, 
    CURRENCY=INR, 
    GATEWAYNAME=HDFC, 
    RESPMSG=Txn Success
    }
]
```

Comment: That looks almost like JSON. Is it supposed to be JSON? It is not valid JSON!

Comment: @RiggsFolly I also think that like a JSON but I really don't know

Comment: I think it not JSON because if it JSON then = is not there in response so definitely it not JSON.

Comment: How do you want to store it in the database?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I want to extract the individual value, like "TXNID", "TXNDATE" etc. and store into database.

Comment: @HP371 I also think that's JSON but the format is something different

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something that is not a particularly useful format for the data response. However this would convert it into a json string which you could store in a database, or make into data that would store into specific columns

```
$s = '[
    {
    STATUS=TXN_SUCCESS, 
    CHECKSUMHASH=hMgfJKzp6a2W91+wVQ71qd58nfvyEsLPgNrnvnYSRYpXDf9YB6+vdtYyejB2w1ZUt1MG8TiASW/jWBRnDO84MM3OlM/+1e5T2tmQ3JasAIw=, 
    BANKNAME=Bank, 
    ORDERID=789ERJSO5HAG, 
    TXNAMOUNT=73.00, 
    TXNDATE=2019-10-27 16:16:39.0, 
    MID=NGtbUJ50332856675382, 
    TXNID=20191027111212800110168691700967146, 
    RESPCODE=01, 
    PAYMENTMODE=DC, 
    BANKTXNID=778001546502320, 
    CURRENCY=INR, 
    GATEWAYNAME=HDFC, 
    RESPMSG=Txn Success
    }
]';

function makeIntoJsonString($string)
{
    $t = str_replace(['[', '{', ']', '}', ' ', "\n"], '', $string);
    $json_string = [];
    foreach ( explode(',', $t) as $pair ) {
        $bits = explode('=', $pair,2);
        $json_string[$bits[0]] = $bits[1];
    }
    return json_encode($json_string);
    // or you could just return the array if you dont want a JSON String
    // return $json_string;
}

$json = makeIntoJsonString($s);
echo $json;
```

RESULT

```
{
    "STATUS":"TXN_SUCCESS",
    "CHECKSUMHASH":"hMgfJKzp6a2W91+wVQ71qd58nfvyEsLPgNrnvnYSRYpXDf9YB6+vdtYyejB2w1ZUt1MG8TiASW\/jWBRnDO84MM3OlM\/+1e5T2tmQ3JasAIw=",
    "BANKNAME":"Bank",
    "ORDERID":"789ERJSO5HAG",
    "TXNAMOUNT":"73.00",
    "TXNDATE":"2019-10-2716:16:39.0",
    "MID":"NGtbUJ50332856675382",
    "TXNID":"20191027111212800110168691700967146",
    "RESPCODE":"01",
    "PAYMENTMODE":"DC",
    "BANKTXNID":"778001546502320",
    "CURRENCY":"INR",
    "GATEWAYNAME":"HDFC",
    "RESPMSG":"TxnSuccess"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But please see the "CHECKSUMHASH" it has replaced the ' = ' within the "CHECKSUMHASH" value. The last one

Comment: Minor fix on the `$bits = explode('=', $pair,2);` line